# Enable JMX on already running process

Tags: java, jmx

I have a processes running in production whose heap I want to investigate without restarting, as it may be leaking memory.  The launch script apparently did not specify the necessary jmxremote parameters.

Is there a way to enable for a process that is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that I'm aware of.  I suggest using `jmap` to take heap dumps of the running process.  You can then use Eclipse MAT to compare them and get an idea of where the leaks are.